# How to watch for changes in value of window variable inside the iFrame?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the code below in the JS file of the iFrame inside my main HTML file to listen for changes in `confedenceVar` variable which is a window variable in my main JS file:

```
var o = { p: parent.window.confedenceVar };
o.watch('p', function () {
  console.log("confedenceVar is changed");
});
```

But unfortunately every time the iFrame loads I get this error:

**Script.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: o.watch is not a function**

How can I watch for any change in `parent.window.confedenceVar`?

Comment: Just a note - you may want to remove the watch method because it has been deprecated. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch : "Deprecation warning: Do not use watch() and unwatch()! These two methods were implemented only in Firefox prior to version 58, they're deprecated and removed in Firefox 58+."

Comment: better way to communicate parrent to iframe scripts use postmessage

Comment: I'm using chrome... So is there any solution for chrome...???

Comment: You might consider using mutationobserver to watch for changes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: A quick hack would be to use setInterval to check every X milliseconds if the oldValue != newValue

Comment: Pure math: How to declare those oldValue !And newValue?